# Syntax of $or in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I tried this code bellow that I found in openclassroom but it's not working, Please help

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{"field" : {"$or" : [{"$gt" : 10}, {"$lt" : 5} ] }
},
{"field":1,"_id":0})

The result is:
Error: error: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "unknown operator: $or",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost right.  refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{"$or" : [{"field" : {"$gt" : 10}}, {"field":{"$lt" : 5}} ] }
},
{"field":1,"_id":0})
```

Comment: Thank you 
I found the syntax in this page
https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4462426-maitrisez-les-bases-de-donnees-nosql/4474606-interrogez-vos-donnees-avec-mongodb
It's an old syntax or just a mistake ?

Comment: Most probably a wrong syntax. But I can't access the link as I need to authorize.